# Can I get the local variables of a Python function from which an exception was thrown?

Tags: python, exception

I'm writing a custom logging system for a project.  If a function throws an exception, I want to log its local variables.  Is it possible to access the raising function's local variables from the except block that caught the exception?  For example:

```
def myfunction():
    v1 = get_a_value()
    raise Exception()

try:
    myfunction()
except:
    # can I access v1 from here?
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's generally cleaner design to pass the value to the exception, if you know that your exception handling code is going to need it. However, if you're writing a debugger or something like that, where you will need to access variables without knowing which ones they are in advance, you *can* access an arbitrary variable in the context where the exception was thrown:

```
def myfunction():
    v1 = get_a_value()
    raise Exception()

try:
    myfunction()
except:
    # can I access v1 from here?
    v1 = inspect.trace()[-1][0].f_locals['v1']
```

The functionality of the `trace` function, and the format of the `traceback` objects it deals with, are described in the [`inspect` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).

Comment: +1 I suspect this is what the OP wanted, even if there's a cleaner way to achieve his/her goal.

Comment: I thought that the "correct" thing to do was use sys.exc_info().  Does it not matter?

Comment: `inspect.trace` is a higher-level interface to the interpreter stack. It uses `sys.exc_info` behind the scenes, though. (The implementation is `return getinnerframes(sys.exc_info()[2], context)`.) While I wouldn't say either way is necessarily _incorrect_, it's probably better form to use the functions of `inspect` because you don't have to worry about the implementation details, plus it's going to make it clearer what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 7):

You can look up the local variables in the frame object, which you can get from `sys.exc_info`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> def f(a):
...     b = a - 1
...     print 1.0 / b
...
>>> try:
...     f(1)
... except Exception, e:
...     print sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals
...
{'a': 1, 'b': 0}
```

You'll have to include the appropriate number of `tb_next`s depending on from how deep in the stack the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 2):

```
def myFunction()
    v1 = get_a_value()
    raise Exception(v1)


try:
    myFunction()
except Exception, e:
    v1 = e.args[0]
```

Comment: `raise Exception(locals())` if you want all the local variables

Comment: @julio.alegria **locals() may be more handy for access in the exception handle, if all the local variables are all needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it's your own exception type. Like this:

```
>>> class MyExn(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...             self.val = val
...     def __str__(self):
...             print "something wrong with:", str(self.val)
... 
>>> def foo():
...     val = 42
...     raise MyExn(val)
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in foo
__main__.MyExnsomething wrong with: 42

>>> # Or in a try block:
>>> try:
...     foo()
... except MyExn as e:
...     print e.val
... 
42
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    myfunction()
except:
    import sys
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    while tb.tb_next:
        tb = tb.tb_next
    frame = tb.tb_frame
    print frame.f_locals['v1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful for "handling" exceptions without using `raise Exception(some_def_var)` and also without using a library such as "inspect", for example.

However, I think if is to handle the exception "in real", might be better to use something like `raise Exception(some_def_var)`. [See @capfredf answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059376/3223785).

```py
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr_I = ""
        self.my_attr_II = ""

    def my_def_I(self):
        try:
            self.my_def_II()
        except Exception as e:
            print(self.my_attr_I)
            print(self.my_attr_II)

    def my_def_II(self):
        self.my_attr_I = "TO EXCEPT I"
        self.my_attr_II = "TO except II"

        # NOTE: We will treat it as a general exception! By Questor
        zero_division = 1/0
```