# SymPy asymptote quirk and how to get around it

Tags: python, sympy

today I stumbled across a curious feature of SymPy. Suppose that we try to evaluate a function at it's asymptote:

```
>>from sympy import *
>>
>>x = Symbol("x")
>>N(cot(x),subs={x: 0})
cot(x)
```

It returns neither a NaN, nor an error or exception, but the function itself! 
My questions:
1. How can I automatically detect that for some point I've stumbled upon an asymptote (besides calling type() on the result)? 
2. What's the motivation behind this design decision?

Comment: Shouldn't you be testing for asymptotes using `limit(cot(x), x, 0, '+')` and `limit(cot(x), x, 0, '-')`?

Comment: Actually, I wanted the values and my way of generating points made me come across this. Well testing the limit from both sides certainly is one option I could take to evade this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer question question 1, you can automatically attempt to make the result to a `float()` as follows:

```
try:
    result=float(N(cot(x),subs={x: 0}))
except Exception as e:
    plus=limit(cot(x), x, 0, '+')
    minus=limit(cot(x), x, 0, '-')
    func=str(inspect.trace()[-1][0].f_locals['result'])
    if plus==minus:
        print("Function %s has a point discontinuity at the point specified. An approximation of the function taking the limit of both sides is %s" % (func,plus))
    else:
        print("Function %s has a jump discontinuity at the point specified" % func)
```

(Thanks to [this question about inspecting locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059349/can-i-get-the-local-variables-of-a-python-function-from-which-an-exception-was-t))

Comment: I am going to add something that gives the value at which the discontinuity occured

Answer (score 2):

Use `subs` on the expression rather than as an argument to `N`:

```
In [3]: N(cot(x).subs(x,0))
Out[3]: zoo
```

This is likely a bug in sympy

Comment: This looks to be a bug in `evalf`.  Reported this to the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it.  Do you mind posting a link to the github issue?

Comment: I added a comment to an [existing issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6974) regarding evalf/subs.