# Using a variable outside of a defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, method-call

If I had a function that I made:

```
def a():
    n = 2*2
```

How could I access n out of the function without calling a?

Comment: A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9059349) comes to mind, although that's about accessing a variable inside a function when you _do_ call the function, so it's not really a duplicate.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326004/access-a-function-variable-outside-the-function-without-using-global)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You will need to define the variable outside of the function, or call the function and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it, so do:

```
def a():
    n = 2*2
    return n
print(a())
```

Output:

```
4
```

You can also do `print`, but `return` is better, check this: [What is the formal difference between "print" and "return"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664779/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-print-and-return)