# Is it possible in Python to run some code upon any exception, without losing scope?

Tags: python, exception, scope, console, try-catch

One of my favorite debug tools is a short piece of code which starts up a console. I sometimes debug by means of (roughly)

```
try: 
    #my code
    ...
except:
    launch_console()
```

However, this requires anticipating where the error will be. If I enclose the entire script in a try/except, I will not have access to any variables within the function I am debugging.

It would be magnificently convenient, if I could run the program and just automatically have `launch_console()` run in case of an error, without losing scope. I think spyder is supposed to have this functionality, but it does not work.

Wondering if there is some nice way to do this!

Comment: Related: [Starting python debugger automatically on error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242485/11082165)

Comment: Also this one (hint: stack frames):  https://stackoverflow.com/q/9059349/5378816

Comment: If this is possible, it's unlikely that you want to react to _any_ exception that's thrown. For example, responding to every `StopIteration` would get tiresome really quick

Comment: @Brian, that post seems nice, but I don't run the python command myself these days, and in Spyder it seems that you can only configure it on a per-file basis; I don't see myself realistically changing the settings each new file I make.

Comment: The comment from VPfB is also helpful, but the trouble is it would require remembering/writing a bunch of code from the sys library before accessing each variable name

Comment: The simple answer is that what you want doesn't really fit the Python model.